# what is the name of this tense "had got put"

Tags: past-tense

I lived around the corner of Dan Treacy and even though we both went to the same God- fearing Catholic grammar school, London Oratory in Fulham. We'd never really spoken to each other. That is until we **'d got put** in the same classes at fourth form

*Ten years ago to go Dan Treacy (extract from Television personalities Fan Club Feb 85)*

What tense is had got put? past perfect of to put why got between had and put
Why did the author choose past perfect (it it is the case), could he have used "were put"

Comment: It's past perfect passive structure: ... *until **we had been put** in the same classes* (by the school) The verb "got" is less formal and is sometimes used in place of the auxiliary "be"  when the speaker talks about actions that were performed by a third party.

Answer (score 1):

It's past perfect passive structure:

> ... *until **we had been put** in the same classes* (by the school)

The verb "got" is less formal and is sometimes used in place of the auxiliary "be"  when the speaker refers to actions that were performed by a third party.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a transcript of someone's actual speech. People do not always speak according to the "rules," but we can understand them anyway, because the human mind is flexible.

In conversation, many people use versions of **get** in a passive construction where the "rules" require a version of **be**. The following are equivalent:

> until we'd **got** put in the same classes at fourth form
> until we'd **been** put in the same classes at fourth form

**we'd** of course is a contraction of **we had**.

So we are looking at a conversational version of the past perfect tense of a verb used in the passive voice.

That said, the past perfect seems odd to me. Based solely on what I read here, I would expect the simple past. The sequence seems to be this:

> We **had** never really spoken to each other . . . until we **were** put in the same classes at fourth form

So the choice of tenses might also be a conversational tic. But I cannot be certain. I don't have a complete sense of what the *reference time* is—that is, the point in time that the tenses are chosen in reference to. To be certain, I would have to read more of the sentences that come before the passage you have quoted. It's possible that all of the tenses are chosen with little attention to the "rules."

Comment: The next 2 sentences are . Although we were quite different, we did discover that we had common interests in music and that we both had guitars. I introduced Dan to some of my pals, John and Bill who I'd known since primary school.